# Filtering file extensions with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I like to search some old files with predefined extensions. (like .doc,.xls,.txt etc.) in a specific folder.
I put the extensions in a variable:

```
$wildcards = @(".txt",".doc",".xls")
```

When I put a new value in this variable it has to change another variable. ($collection)

Here is my code:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem C:\test\test1\
$date = (Get-Date).Add(-1)
$wildcards = @(".txt",".doc",".xls")


function Get-WildCards { 

$counter = 0;
$counterEnd = $wildcards.Count
$collection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
$filter = "$" + "_.Extension" + " -like $" + "wildcards[" + $counter + "]}"
$or = " -or "

    for ($counter = 0; $counter -lt $counterEnd; $counter++) {

        $filter = "$" + "_.Extension" + " -like $" + "wildcards[" + $counter + "]}"
        $collection += $filter + $or
    }

$collection = [String]::Join('', $collection)
$collection = $collection.ToString()
$collection = $collection.TrimEnd($or)
} 

Get-WildCards

$folderPath = $folder.FullName

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File:$true |
 Where-Object {$collection} 

$files
```

If I run this code the Where-Object condition won't work this way.
It won't filter the extensions. 
How can I achieve that it works?
Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be complicating things. Try this -

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem C:\test\test1\
$wildcards = @(".txt",".doc",".xls")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath | where {$_.extension -in $wildcards}
$files
```

Comment: Ah, I do. Thank you Vivek. :) I note this "-in" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, take advantage of the -Include parameter of Get-ChildItem.  I'm assuming items and childitems are not being sought for recursively.

```
$mypath = 'c:\test\test1'
$myext  = @('*.txt','*.doc','*.xls')
Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Include $myext
```

Comment: dir need a `*` star char, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4#example-4-get-child-items-using-the-include-parameter:~:text=Example%204%3A%20Get%20child%20items%20using%20the%20Include%20parameter